# Python3 web automation error - ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webautomation

New to coding and programming here. Just wondering if anyone knows why the code below is returning an "ElementNotInteractableException" error? It seems to be coming from the "search" part because I run the code without it an I did not get an error. I am trying to automate a YouTube search for "cat videos". I'm able to open YouTube but not perform the typing on the search bar. Thanks a lot!

Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://youtube.com')

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
*search.send_keys('cat videos')*

searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchButton.click()
```

Comment: I saw you rejected my edit. I was just trying to help. Your writing style here sounds arrogant, and the code formatting was missing. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Armando, thanks for your feedback and for letting me know that the comment I saw was a legit comment, & that posts can be edited by other users that way. I had no intention to offend you. I thought it was just a random Stackoverflow notification because it did not show any solution so I just got rid of it w/o really understanding what that whole edit permission notification that I got, meant. I am new here & am still learning how to navigate this system. Thanks for trying to help me (was actually wondering how to format the code) and I'm sorry I offended you. Please send your edit again.

Comment: All good ;) you can format your code with a tripple tick ```